# Entity Framework exception after migrating WPF application to .net Framework 4.5.1

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, .net-framework-version

I have updated .Net framework of one WPF complex application from 3.5 to 4.5.1.
I have changed Target Framework for all projects as 4.5.1.

After changing .net framework I am getting below error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll
>
> Inner Exception message : -"The mapping and metadata information for EntityContainer 'ApplicationNameDataContext' no longer matches the information used to create the pre-generated views."

Any thoughts why this is happening?

Application running fine with VS2010 and .Net frmwrk 3.5.
Project have 4.0.0.0 version of System.Data.Entity Dll.

Comment: Did you update Entiry Framework 4/5 to version 6 at the same time?  If so, I think you are going to need to regenerate the entity model.  Microsoft has migration info posted on MSDN.

Comment: Add `System.Xaml` to references.

Comment: Also check `WindowsBase` and `PresentationFramework` and `PresentationCore` and `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching I found that if I change all Schema of edmx back to old it start working.

Right click on edmx open it with text editor and change below lines.

```
1.    
    <edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">  
  to  <edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">

2.    
    <Schema Namespace="Application.Model.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2005" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">  
 to 
     <Schema Namespace="Application.Model.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2005" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm/ssdl">

3    
    <edmx:ConceptualModels> <Schema Namespace="Application.Model" Alias="Self" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation"> 
  to
    <edmx:ConceptualModels> <Schema Namespace="Application.Model" Alias="Self" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation">

4    
    <edmx:Mappings>
          <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs">
     to
    <edmx:Mappings>
    <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:windows:storage:mapping:CS">

5  And in   <edmx:Designer>  change 

    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx  to 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx.
```

I am not sure this is a correct way or not but it resolve the issues for me.